# JavaIO Stream returns different bits

Tags: java, arrays, stream, byte, inputstream

```
@GET
@Path("/hello-message")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getMessage() throws Exception {
    char[] array = {'h','e','l','l','o', 2000, 3000, 9999};
    CharArrayReader charArrayReader = new CharArrayReader(array);
    int c = 0;
    while ((c = charArrayReader.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.println(c + " " + Integer.toBinaryString(c) + " " +(char)c);
    }
    return Response.status(200).entity(charArrayReader).build();
}
```

When the above REST api is hit, this is what get's printed,

```
104 1101000 h
101 1100101 e
108 1101100 l
108 1101100 l
111 1101111 o
2000 ߐ 11111010000
3000 101110111000 ஸ
9999 10011100001111 ✏
```

Clearly I'm using Unicode (last 3 char's in array) and hence, these are the Physical BITS (only the bits part above), I think will be transferred via the underlying network.

But, when I receive the response, I get it as InputStream from the apache HTTP api.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:80/hello-message");
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        int c = -1;
        while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.println(c + " " + Integer.toBinaryString(c));
        }
    }
}
```

When I iterated over the bytes in the InputStream, this is what I received,

```
104 1101000
101 1100101
108 1101100
108 1101100
111 1101111
223 11011111
144 10010000
224 11100000
174 10101110
184 10111000
226 11100010
156 10011100
143 10001111
```

1. For first 5 characters which is h,e,l,l,o, both the API method and the response I received had exactly same bits.
2. When it is beyond ASCII limit, why is the below discrepancy,
   eg., for unicode 2000,

   ```
    In API method it printed = 11111010000,
    In Response it printed = 11011111 (223) followed by 10010000 (144) which clearly doesn't matches above. I expected 11111010000 will be broken into 2 bytes like 00000111 (7) 11010000 (208), but I received something else like, 223 and 114.
   ```

But when I read through IOUtils library, I'm getting correct response,

```
String s = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), UTF_8);
System.out.println(s);
```

This prints the string same as the char array returned by the API method

```
helloߐஸ✏
```

Any reason for this behaviour? How did stream put the pieces back and formed the correct message?

Comment: The **tl;dr** is: you're looking at unicode characters first and at the encoded bytestream later. The difference is the "encoding" used to transfer it.In your case it's UTF-8 (which is even mentioned in your code).

Answer (score -2):

Eww! I really typed a very long question for which I trumbled for a day just to find out the answer in the very next minute.

This 9-minutes video is golden: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4

Comment: Self-answers are fine. Link-only answers are not: please include the relevant detail into the answer, otherwise it's not a valid answer.